# Gulp: How can I build filename.pug to filename/index.html

Tags: html, gulp, pug-loader

Now I'm using gulp-pug

```
gulp.task('html', function(){
    return gulp.src(['src/**/*.pug', ...ignorePug])
        .pipe(pug())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
});
```

How can I build my HTML, so that file names are folder names.

Example:

```
src/index.pug -> build/index.html
src/team.pug -> build/team/index.html
src/somepage.pug -> build/somepage/index.html
```

Comment: Alexander, if you're still working with gulp and pug, the update I made to my answer may interest you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

I've published an npm package and gulp plugin here to address this exact issue: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-url-builder

---

### Original Answer

I had the same desire and wrote a function that uses [gulp-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename) to rewrite the file paths as they're being processed.

After you run `pug()`, run `rename()` with this function:

```
// custom pathbuilder function
const pathbuilder = (path) => {
    if ('index' !== path.basename) {
        path.dirname = path.basename.split('_').join('/')
        path.basename = 'index'
    }
}

gulp.task('html', function(){
    return gulp.src(['src/**/*.pug', ...ignorePug])
        .pipe( pug() )
        .pipe( rename((path) => { pathbuilder(path) }) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest('build') )
})
```

It's set up to do what you're looking for. Additionally, you can use underscores to go deeper in directories.

```
src/index.pug          -> build/index.html
src/team.pug           -> build/team/index.html
src/team_alexander.pug -> build/team/alexander/index.html
src/somepage.pug       -> build/somepage/index.html
```

Be sure to install and require the rename package first.